# Blurring a picture over java with a double array represents the set of pixels

Tags: java, gaussianblur

> Write a function called "smooth", which blurs the picture - a double array represents the group of pixels of the picture. Smoothing a picture for a parameter n, is taking all pixel in the picture to be the average of n*n neighbors. Meaning that is looking at a n*n square which the current pixel is his center, and replace the pixel with the average of the neighbors.

---

***My attempt:***
So I have written the following:

```
public void smooth(int n) {
    int N = (n-1)/2;
    for (int x = N; x<frame.length-N;x++){
        for (int y=N;y<frame[x].length-N;y++){
            frame[x][y]=average(x,y,N,this.frame);
        }
    }
    //for edges:
    for (int x = 0; x<frame.length;x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < frame[0].length; y++) {
            if (FilterOutOfBounds(x,y,this.frame,N)!=-1) frame[x][y] = FilterOutOfBounds(x, y, this.frame, N);
        }
    }

}
public static int average(int x, int y, int N,int[][] frame){
    int sum = 0, cnt=0;
    for (int i = x-N;i<x+N;i++){
        for (int j = y-N;j<y+N;j++){
            sum+=frame[i][j]; cnt++;
        }
    }
    return sum/cnt;
}

public static int FilterOutOfBounds(int x, int y, int[][] frame, int N){
    int cnt = 0,sum=0;
    if (frame[0].length-1-y<N && x!=frame.length-1){
        for (int j = y;j>=y-1;j--){
            for (int i = x;i<=x+1;i++){
                cnt++;
                sum+=frame[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    else if (y<N && x!=frame.length-1 ){
        for (int j = y;j<=y+1;j++){
            for (int i = x;i<=x+1;i++){
                cnt++;
                sum+=frame[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    else if(frame.length-x<N && y!=0){
        for (int i = x;i>=x-1;i--){
            for (int j = y;j>=y-1;j--){
                cnt++;
                sum+=frame[i][j];
            }
        }

    }

    else if (x<N && y!=frame.length-1){
        for (int i = x;i<=x+1;i++){
            for (int j = y;j<=y+1;j++){
                cnt++;
                sum+=frame[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    if (cnt==0) return -1;
    return sum/cnt;
}
```

***However***, it doesn't blur the edges for a certain reason, and I can't think why. Therefore, I will be glad for some help. Thanks!

- By the way, "Frame" in the code is a property of the class and it is the double array represents the pixels of a gray picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some issues with your code. First, you are directly updating the `frame` variable, which will accumulate the average values for your calculation. I believe this is also an unwanted side-effect.
An other thing is, that the `FilterOutOfBounds` method uses `frame.length` against `y`, which shall be `frame[0].length`, as this refers to `y` for a rectangle. Also these inner calculations does not handle `N`, so the `x+1` and `y+1` in the for loops are probably misconcepts, they should be `x+N` and `y+N` or something similar.

I have created a more simple solution for your question. Basically I have modified the `avarage` method, to be able to handle edge cases and let the `smooth` for loop to iterate over every cell of `frame`. Worked for me:

```
public void smooth( int n ) {
    int N = (n - 1) / 2;
    int[][] blurred = new int[frame.length][frame[0].length];
    for ( int x = 0; x < frame.length; x++ ) {
        for ( int y = 0; y < frame[x].length; y++ ) {
            blurred[x][y] = average(x, y, N, frame);
        }
    }
    frame = blurred;
}

public static int average( int x, int y, int N, int[][] frame ) {
    int sum = 0, cnt = 0;
    for ( int i = Math.max(x - N, 0); i <= Math.min(x + N, frame.length - 1); i++ ) {
        for ( int j = Math.max(y - N, 0); j <= Math.min(y + N, frame[i].length - 1); j++ ) {
            sum += frame[i][j];
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return sum / cnt;
}
```

Comment: I got you! Thank you very much, I didn't think to do what you have done. Wonderful answer, which extends mine.